# Uniformly continuous on metric space

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ and on $[1,\infty)$ where $f:[0,\infty) \to X$, $X$ any metric space. Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

I have no idea where to start the proof. How do these uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ and on $[1,\infty)$ imply that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$? Can someone help me please?

Comment: Start by writing down the definition of uniform continuity, so that you know what you have to show.

Comment: Given a $\delta_1$ and a $\delta_2$ can you figure out a $\delta$ that works for both cases?

Comment: I understand this method but what should I do to the case where $y<1<x$?

Comment: Use $|f(x) - f(y)| \le |f(x) - f(1)| + |f(y) - f(1)|$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon >0$. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$, there is a $\delta_{1}>0$ such that $x,y\in[0,1]\text{ and }|x-y|<\delta_{1}\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon/2$. Similarly, since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty)$, there is a $\delta_{2}>0$ such that $x,y\in[1,\infty)\text{ and }|x-y|<\delta_{2}\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon/2$.

Now, let $\delta=\min\{\delta_{1},\delta_{2}\}$. Let $x,y\in[0,\infty)$ be such that $|x-y|<\delta$. Then, if $x,y\in[0,1]$ or $x,y\in[1,\infty)$, the above implies that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon/2<\epsilon$. Otherwise, suppose without loss of generality, that $x\in[0,1]$ and $y\in[1,\infty)$. By the triangle inequality, it follows that

$$
|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)-f(1)+f(1)-f(y)|\leq |f(x)-f(1)|+|f(1)-f(y)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.
$$